# REST javascript client

Tags: javascript, rest, asp.net-web-api

Are there any best practices for javascript REST clients. Specifically, I would like to know 
how to follow links.
Let say I have a Task class

```
public class Task
{
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
```

Let say instance of this service model class is sent to javascript client:

```
{
    TaskId : '1',
    Subject : 'Some',
    Completed: false,
    Canceled : false,
    Links : [{Rel:'Completed', URL:'http://myadress/tasks/1/complete'}, 
             {Rel:'Canceled ', URL:'http://myadress/tasks/1/cancel'}]

}
```

Now I would like to complete this task. That should be done by following the link with Rel : Completed. But how to do that? Should I just POST to URL and grab new representation of task, or should I create something like

```
var x = {
    TaskId : '1',
    Subject : 'Some',
    Completed: false,
    Canceled : false,
    complete : function(callback){ 
               // post to completed URL, and callback with new representation
               }
    Links : [{Rel:'Complete', URL:'http://myadress/tasks/1/complete'}, 
             {Rel:'Cancel ', URL:'http://myadress/tasks/1/cancel'}]    
}

x.complete(callback);
```

or create dedicated function?

```
function completeTask(task, callback){
var url = //search links property for rel:Colmplete and get URL
//complete task
//callback with the new representation

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it might give you inspiration. Check out the Node.js module unio (https://github.com/ttezel/unio). As an alternative to HATEOAS, it prefers mapping a REST API in a JSON spec and provides a generic client that uses the spec to understand and consume the API. Even if you can't use unio directly, it might give you some ideas for developing your client code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't live in the Javascript world but I believe the approach that I take would still be valid.  I create objects that correlate to the link relations.  Therefore you would have a `completeLink` object and 'cancelLink' object that knows how to make the HTTP request.

The only information they are missing is the URI that you would extract from the representation.  Optionally clients can change the default callback behavior as not all clients are going to do the same thing with the response from a link.  However, all clients should be able to reuse the logic to actually make the HTTP request as the link relation explicitly defines that behavior.

I would be very interested to see how that would look in JS.  I wish I knew the language better.